# How to leave more room between two lines

Tags: cases

I have this case formula which I need to make a little more readable by adding a little more space, vertically, between the two cases.

```
\begin{cases} f = -\frac {w_1*m + w_2*\frac{-d}{d_M} + w_3*\frac{r}{N} + w_4*s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} &\hbox{when }m \geq t \\ f = -\frac {w_1*m + 5*w_2*\frac{-d}{d_M} + w_3*\frac{r}{N} + w_4*s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} & \hbox{when } m< t \end{cases}
```

[image]

How to add an extra space in the latex case above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to increase vertical space between lines in `cases` by `\\[1em]`:

```
\[
    \begin{cases} 
f = -\dfrac {w_1*m + w_2*\frac{-d}{d_M} 
        + w_3*\frac{r}{N} + w_4*s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} 
    &   \text{when }m \geq t    \\[3ex]% this increase vertical space between lines
f = -\dfrac {w_1*m + 5*w_2*\frac{-d}{d_M} 
        + w_3*\frac{r}{N} + w_4*s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} 
    & \text{when } m< t 
    \end{cases}
\]
```

Result:

[image]

If you like to have more space, than increase distance between lines. I also suggest to `\dfrac` instead `\frac` or even better use the `dcases` environment instead of `cases`. To my taste equation will look better. For `dcases` you need to add package `mathtools` to preamble of your document, but no `\dfrac` is needed. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{dcases} 
f = -\frac {w_1\cdot m + w_2\cdot \frac{-d}{d_M} 
        + w_3\cdot \frac{r}{N} + w_4\cdot s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} 
    &   \text{when }m \geq t    \\
f = -\frac {w_1\cdot m + 5\cdot w_2\cdot \frac{-d}{d_M} 
        + w_3\cdot \frac{r}{N} + w_4\cdot s}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4} 
    & \text{when } m< t 
    \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip on dfrac! This looks so much better indeed.

Comment: better to use a dimension intended for vertical measure, e.g. `ex`.  (`em` is for horizontal measure.)  but better still, try `\openup\jot` which increases the distance between lines in a math structure locally by 3pt.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you for comment. I will correct vertical measure in my answer. Possibilities `openup` is new to me. Where I can find some explanation about it?

Comment: The `dcases` environment is provided by `mathtools`, not `empheq`. The side conditions are better input as `\text{when $m\geq t$}` and `\text{when $m<t$}`. With the `dcases*` environment (again requires `mathtools`) they can be input as `when $m\geq t$` and `when $m<t$`, because text mode is implicit after the `&`.

Comment: @egreg, wel, my document, by which i generate equation in my answer, has `empheq`, not `mathtools` Does `ampheq` call `mathtools`? About writing text in `cases` I agree with you, I just didn't bother with this.

Comment: @Zarko Line 56 of `empheq.sty` says `\RequirePackage{mathtools}[2004/10/10]`

Comment: @egreg, thank you for this information. I will correct my answer accordingly and in my other documents stop to load bot document. When using `empheq` I will left to it to call `mathtools` :-)