# Insert vertical spacing between cases

Tags: cases, vertical-spacing

How does one insert some vertical spacing between two cases for the output of the following script?

```
\begin{cases}
a+b \\
c+d 
\end{cases}
```

Comment: for example: `\begin{cases}
a+b \\[3ex]
c+d 
\end{cases}` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to leave more room between two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270220/how-to-leave-more-room-between-two-lines) (at least your question has "cases" in the title, but the one linked is about cases too, as are many other similar questions, including one asked today.)

Comment: @Zarko: and DonaldArseneau  Thank you, both. Just curious. Does '[ ]' mean '\vspace'? Is there a corresponding command for inserting horizontal spacing between, say, columns? I know I can use '\hspace{2ex}' between characters. Would a corresponding script be '(2ex)'?

Comment: It has the same effect, it insert vertical space of given lenght (3 height of letter x in showed example). For horizontal space, you can use for example  `\hspace{1em}` after ampesand, or for example `\quad` : `\[
\begin{cases}
a+b &\quad xy\\[1ex]
c+d &\quad uw
\end{cases}
\]`.

Comment: Yes, \\ takes an optional argument (of a flexible length) for the space to add below the line, but I must apologize that it is *not* the same as \vspace in the tabular or array or cases environments! In those situations it acts like a temporary increase of \baselineskip that may be overwhelmed by very tall contents on the line.